# Best way to get list of all users with Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask-login

Learning Flask-Login for user management.  The following works, but I'd like to know if there are other / better ways to do it...

**What is the best way to get a list of all users in my user table and send it to my admin.html template page?**

USER MODEL:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, username, password, admin):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.admin = admin

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username
```

LOGIN MANAGER:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter_by(username=user_id).first()

def load_all_users():
    return User.query.all()
```

ADMIN ROUTE:

```
@app.route("/admin/")
@login_required
def admin():
    if current_user.admin:
        users = load_all_users()
        return render_template("admin.html", userlist=users)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

ADMIN HTML TEMPLATE:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Admin Area</h1>
                {% for eachuser in userlist %}
                    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1ex">
                        <div>
                            {{ eachuser.username }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your thoughts on this!

Comment: The question is a bit vague but you probably don't want to "load all users". There should be some sort of pagination but that wasn't the question

Comment: This is the way I would go about doing it. It seems perfectly fine to me.